# How to convert string value in to date datattype in oracle

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I am getting date value from excel file as '2015.08',`2015.09` etc.I am reading these excel file by using c# code and now i want to insert in to oracle table contains field 'manufacturedate' which of datatype `DATE`.How i can convert value '2015.08' in to oracle datatype 'DATE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do in your code, and pass it to database as date

```cs
DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(iString, "yyyy.MM",null);
```

Or you can convert it at db level (but shouldn't)

```sql
insert into my_table (manufacturedate)
values (to_date(:p_not_real_date, 'yyyy.mm'))
```